# How to use a shared library in visual studio

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries

I'm in trouble with visual studio and have no idea what else I should try.

I bundled some c++ functions in a shared library (dll/windows) and tried to include that library in visual studio.

The problem is that visual studio always prints the following error:

> error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl CppFunc(void)" (__imp_?CppFunc@@YAXXZ)" in function "main"

Because I thought that it is my fault, I tried the following example:
[Building a Dynamic-Link Library using C++ MinGW](http://xathrya.web.id/blog/2013/07/21/building-a-dynamic-link-library-using-c-mingw/)

If I use the console to compile that example everything works just fine. On the other hand I recieve the same errors as with my library as I try to compile in visual studio.

This is what I tried to get it working:

- created an include directory and copied all header in this directory
- created a lib directory and copied the .lib and the .dll file in this directory
- used cmake and the following CMakeLists.txt-File to generate the visual studio project

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1)
  project (Tutorial)

  include_directories(include)

  add_library(lib SHARED IMPORTED)
  set_property(TARGET lib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/my_dll.dll)
  set_property(TARGET lib PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libmy_dll.lib)

  file(GLOB srcfiles
      "src/*.cpp"
  )

  add_executable(Tutorial ${srcfiles})
  target_link_libraries(Tutorial lib)
  ```

To generate the .dll and the .lib file the following command is used by me:

```
g++ -c -DBUILD_MY_DLL my_dll.cpp
g++ -shared -o my_dll.dll my_dll.o -Wl,--subsystem,windows,--out-implib,libmy_dll.lib
```

I would be really happy, if someone could help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two completely different linkers. Using the .a or .dll.a or .lib file of a gcc/g++/mingw library is rarely ever going to work out of the box with MSVC. Rebuild the library using MSVC and link to the rebuilt one. Otherwise you're going to have to load every function from the library via `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: Also consider `extern "C" { ... }` for DLLs or you will have issues even with `GetProcAddress` due to the decorated name.

Comment: I tried both possible solutions. If I compile the dll over visual studio the resulting .lib file is the same as with gcc. And it is still not working.